# Azure AD B2C UI customization for custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How can i use my own designed UI for azure AD B2C custom policies.
i am using [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email)
sample for custom policy.

Answer (score 0):

[A content definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization) enables a custom flow to refer to a custom page.

For example, if you're wanting to show a custom page for the sign-up or sign-in step, then you must set the `LoadUri` attribute of the **api.signuporsignin** `ContentDefinition` element, as follows:

```xml
<BuildingBlocks>
  <ContentDefinitions>
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
      <LoadUri>https://contoso.blob.core.windows.net/templates/unified.html</LoadUri>
      <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
      <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
      </Metadata>
    </ContentDefinition>
  </ContentDefinitions>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

Note that the sign-up or sign-in step references the **api.signuporsignin** content definition as follows:

```xml
<UserJourneys>
  <UserJourney>
    <OrchestrationSteps>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
```

For more information about content definitions, see [this reference article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions).