# Customize signup page using api.signuporsignin and custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using api.signuporsignin on my journey and have customized the login page, but when I clic on signup link, it goes to MS default signup page instead of a custom signup. I saw this link goes to

https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/unified?local=signup...

Is there a way to customize the signup page using api.signuporsignin?

Here's my journey

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpWithEmailOrSignInWithUsernameOrEmail">
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninUsernameExchange" />
                    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninUsernameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                <Preconditions>
                    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                    <Value>objectId</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                    </Precondition>
                </Preconditions>
                <ClaimsExchanges>
                    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
                </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>

...

<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username">
                <DisplayName>Local Account Signin with Username</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item>
                    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.test</Item>
                </Metadata>
```

thanks

EDIT 1: Add content definition. I could customize signin page but not signup. When you clic on *signup now* link, the default MS page appears

```
<ContentDefinitions>
        <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
            <LoadUri>https://something.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/custom-ui.html</LoadUri>
            <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
            <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
            <Metadata>
                <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
            </Metadata>
        </ContentDefinition>
        <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.test">
            <LoadUri>https://something.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/custom-signup.html</LoadUri>
            <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri>
            <Metadata>
            <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
            </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
```

Comment: Did you set the `LoadUri` attribute of the **api.signuporsignin** `ContentDefinition` element? As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60544820/azure-ad-b2c-ui-customization-for-custom-policy?answertab=votes#tab-top) suggested.

Comment: yes. signin page is with new layout, but not signup. I added my content definitions

Comment: Hi gllambi, I believe the problem that you are experiencing is related to the content definition that is being used on the signup technical profile. Can you please post the signup profile code and the code for the relevant content definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your trust framework base definitions and the (unposted) rest of your user journey.

The sign-up or sign in page only provides the links to the "sign up" page - which works by basically skipping the orchestration step. A second orchestration step after the sign-up or sign in page will generally test if a user object ID claim exists (e.g. - if the user actually logged in or not), and then run a sign-up step with a separate content definition if the user is trying to sign up and not sign in...

For example, in the base policies provided by MS:

```xml
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
      
        <!-- Present the sign up or sign in page, with `api.signuporsignin` -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- 
            If the previous step did not generate a user object ID (IE - 
            sign the user in), show the sign up page.
 
            The `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail` technical profile 
            should use a diffrent content definion because it's a self-assert
            profile - in this case `api.localaccountsignup` - You'll need to
            customize this content definition too.
         -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! I was using LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail techprofile. Updated the api.localaccountsignup content definition and worked!

Answer (score 0):

As @Allen Wu suggested,searching for the ***'api.signuporsignin'*** in ***TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml***,check if ***Loaduri*** is consistent with the url you set in your ***Azure AD protal->storge account ->container***.

```
  <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
    <LoadUri>https://storage1.blob.core.windows.net/root/custom-ui.html</LoadUri>
    <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
    <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
      <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.en" />
      <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.signuporsignin.es" />
    </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
  </ContentDefinition>
```

Comment: yes, I added the content definition I use on the post